# non-decreasing sequences

Tags: calculus

I have the following sequence

$\{n^4-6n^2\}$

I have to determine if the sequence is non-decreasing, increasing or decreasing.

In my opinion, the sequence is neither, decreasing, non-decreasing nor increasing because it seems to be increasing for all the terms except for the first and second term. Am I right or I am right?

By the way,is there category for such a sequence? where you have an interval of increasing terms and one of decreasing terms or is such a sequence not even possible?

Comment: I suppose this depends on what you define.  To me the fact that this sequence is $\textit {eventually}$ increasing is critical.  The initial terms don't have much significance for the long range behavior.  But, as I say, one can define whatever one wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polynomial factorises as $n^2(n^2-6),$ which vanishes somewhere between $n=2$ and $n=3$ if we for the moment think of $n$ as a real variable. It then increases afterwards. Thus, you're right that it cannot be monotonic.

Sequences that are not monotonic may generally be classified as oscillating.

Comment: "Sequences that are not monotonic may generally be classified as oscillating"  I would not call the above sequence oscillating.  An oscillating sequence would be one whose [oscillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_(mathematics)#Oscillation_of_a_sequence) is defined and nonzero.

Comment: @JMoravitz I like to think of oscillations as being possibly infinite.

Comment: yes, and they can be, such as the sequence $n\cdot (-1)^n$ which goes $\{0,-1,2,-3,4,-5,\dots\}$.  That oscillation would be infinite.  From any point in the sequence, you can look ahead and see there will be some back and forth motion.  Another prototypical example of an oscillating sequence would be $\{1,2,-1,-2,1,2,-1,-2,\dots\}$ where it always has this back and forth motion now and always and has an oscillation of $4$.  The sequence above however does not oscillate, there is no back and forth repeatedly forever motion.  Once you pass a certain point it grows and never comes back down.

Comment: @JMoravitz It's a matter of however you want to classify your sequences. I see that you want your definition of *oscillating sequence* to abide by the intuition of a *continuously* oscillating object, but I simply think of the term as being an anti-class of the monotonic sequences -- that is, an oscillating sequence is one that is not monotonic; it matters little whether the oscillation is transient or eternal. And indeed, in the solution of second order differential equations, we have such a concept as a *damped oscillation,* which don't always vibrate forever as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$a_n=n^4-6n^2$$ then $$a_{n+1}-a_n=(n+1)^4-6(n+1)^2-(n^4-6n^2)=…$$